# How to render and update child elements coming from a parent component in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a problem with a collection of strings owned by a parent component and rendered in a child component. I achieved that and I can also execute a parent method (delete) from the child component. But when the collection gets updated in the parent, it's not updated in the child view. Any idea?

This is the parent:

```
export class App extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      countries: ['Country 1', 'Country 2', 'Country 3']
    };
  }

  deleteCountry = (name) => {
    this.setState(this.state.countries.filter(country => country !== name));
  }

  render() {
    return <Router>
      <NavBar></NavBar>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact component={Jobs}></Route>
        <Route path="/countries" exact render={(props) => <Countries {...props} collection={this.state.countries} delete={this.deleteCountry}/>}></Route>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  }
}
export default App;
```

And this is the child:

```
export class Countries extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>
      <h3>Countries</h3>
      <ul>
        {this.props.collection.map((country) => { 
          return <li key={country}>
            {country}
            <button onClick={() => this.props.delete(country)}>Eliminar</button>
          </li>
        })}
      </ul>
    </div>;
  }
}
```

Thank you so much for your attention!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like your `deleteCountry` method is not setting the correct key in state:

```js
deleteCountry = (name) => {
  this.setState({
    countries: this.state.countries.filter(country => country !== name)
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you!!! I really can't understand how I missed that!!! :)

Comment: Happens to all of us!